# Using Grep or AWK command

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have file with this text information:

```
http://=
en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=1D7f1ad404-f84b-4a3b-8931=
-4f40b619730e



http://=
en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=5D8172f6e6-240f-42e6-8512=
-6d7f6bd61c2d



http://=
en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=8D8172f6e6-240f-42e6-8512=
-6d7f6bd61c2d
```

How i can do this using grep or awk command in linux bash:

```
http://en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=1D7f1ad404-f84b-4a3b-8931-4f40b619730e
http://en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=5D8172f6e6-240f-42e6-8512-6d7f6bd61c2d
http://en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=8D8172f6e6-240f-42e6-8512-6d7f6bd61c2d
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="=\n"; RS=""; OFS=""} {print $1, $2, $3}' input_file
```

You could also get rid of `OFS=""` and remove the `,`s in the print statement

Answer (score 0):

Save the program as **pr.awk**, and run `awk -f pr.awk input.dat`

```
NF {
    n++
    sub(/=$/, "")
    ans = ans $0
}

n==3 { # flush
    print ans
    ans = ""; n = 0 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/=$/{sub(/=$/,""); printf "%s",$0;next} /./{print}' file
http://en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=1D7f1ad404-f84b-4a3b-8931-4f40b619730e
http://en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=5D8172f6e6-240f-42e6-8512-6d7f6bd61c2d
http://en.domain.com/registration.html#/?doitoken=8D8172f6e6-240f-42e6-8512-6d7f6bd61c2d
```

How it works:

- `/=$/{sub(/=$/,""); printf "%s",$0;next}`

  If the line ends with `=`, then remove the trailing `=`, print the result (without a trailing newline) and jump to the `next` line.
- `/./{print}`

  If we get here, then this line does not end with `=` and we just print it normally (with the trailing newline).